# How to add new line in string?

Tags: php, html, string

It is showing me the strings combined together. How can I make the strings of product_short_description display on two lines, one above the other? Because my online shopping API just can receive stings. So I must using *strip_tags* to remove tag.

Here is code:

```
<?php


include '../db_config/db_conn.php';

$sql = 'SELECT c1.entity_id AS product_id, c1.sku, c2.value AS prdNm, 
c3.value AS product_price, 
c5.value AS category_name, c6.value AS weight, c7.value AS image, c8.value 
AS description, 
c9.value AS price,c11.value AS shipment_type,c12.value AS 
warranty,c13.value AS short_description
FROM catalog_product_entity c1
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar c2 ON c1.entity_id=c2.entity_id 
AND c2.attribute_id=71
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_decimal c3 ON c1.entity_id=c3.entity_id 
AND c3.attribute_id=75
LEFT JOIN catalog_category_product c4 ON c1.entity_id=c4.product_id
LEFT JOIN catalog_category_entity_varchar c5 ON 
c5.entity_id=c4.category_id AND c5.attribute_id=41
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_decimal c6 ON c1.entity_id=c6.entity_id 
AND c6.attribute_id=80
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar c7 ON c1.entity_id=c7.entity_id 
AND c7.attribute_id=85
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_text c8 ON c1.entity_id=c8.entity_id AND 
c8.attribute_id=72
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_decimal c9 ON c1.entity_id=c9.entity_id 
AND c9.attribute_id=75
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_int c11 ON c1.entity_id=c11.entity_id AND 
c11.attribute_id=127
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_int c12 ON c1.entity_id=c12.entity_id AND 
c12.attribute_id=154
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_text c13 ON c1.entity_id=c13.entity_id 
AND c13.attribute_id=73
WHERE c1.entity_id = 200

';
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$product_id = $row['product_id'];
$product_sku = $row['sku'];
$product_name = $row['prdNm'];
$product_price = $row['product_price'];
$product_category_name = $row['category_name'];
$product_weight = $row['weight'];
$product_image = $row['image'];
$product_description = $row['description'];
$product_price = $row['price'];
$product_shipment_type = $row['shipment_type'];
$product_warranty = $row['warranty'];
$product_short_description = $row['short_description'];

}

$product_short_description = strip_tags($product_short_description);

$curl = curl_init();


curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.11street.my/rest/prodservices/product",
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" 
standalone=\"yes\"?>
<Product>
<selMthdCd>01</selMthdCd>
<dispCtgrNo>4932</dispCtgrNo>
<prdTypCd>01</prdTypCd>
<prdNm>$product_name</prdNm>
<prdStatCd>01</prdStatCd>
<prdWght>$product_weight</prdWght>
<minorSelCnYn>Y</minorSelCnYn>
<prdImage01>$product_image</prdImage01>
<htmlDetail>$product_short_description</htmlDetail>

</Product>",
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
"cache-control: no-cache",
"content-type: application/xml",
"openapikey: dsfewlkhrt2k3h4jk2hredfsdcvsd",
 ),
 ));

 $response = curl_exec($curl);
 $err = curl_error($curl);

 curl_close($curl);

 echo $response;
```

The output is shown in below (It is showing me the strings combined together):

```
Model : 3M7502What's in the box : 1 Piece Mask
```

Actually I’m trying to achieve this result（*product_short_description* display on two lines）:

```
Model : 3M7502
What's in the box : 1 Piece Mask
```

Hope someone can help me to solve *product_short_description* display on two lines. Thanks.

Comment: Try to use [nl2br()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) like so: `echo nl2br($product_short_description);` There is a change that that will work.

Comment: thanks. It is possible change in $product_short_description = strip_tags($product_short_description);?

Comment: I don't see why you would want to remove HTML tags. What does this have to do with your question?

Comment: HI Kiko. Because my online shopping API just can receive stings. So that I want to using strip_tags to remove tags.

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry, I can't help you in that case.

Comment: I'm not sure all your code is in the question.  Where are you combining strings?

Comment: I'm assuming your "shopping API" requires payment information to go through it, in which case you most definitely should **not** be using the deprecated `mysql_query` *facepalm*

Comment: I want insert product description into the online shopping website. My online shopping website just can allow me to insert string

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to add a newline between two strings, you can just do either:

```
echo $string1 . "\n" . $string2;
echo "$string1\n$string2";
```

The `""` around the `\n` is important, it won't work if you use single quotes: `'\n'`

Comment: And how is Ason Chee Soon going to get `$string1` and `$string2`?

Answer (score 0):

Well, assuming that there is a `<br>` tag in `$product_short_description` you could do:

```
list($modelNo, $inTheBox) = explode("<br>", $product_short_description);
```

where `$modelNo` will contain the model number `Model : 3M7502` and `$inTheBox` will contain `What's in the box : 1 Piece Mask`.

But this *will only work* if there actually is a `<br>` in the database string, and you are now left with two strings instead of one.

Comment: Thanks. But the database include html tag

Comment: Oh dear. How could we have known? Might it be the `<br>` tag, or is it another? And is splitting the string on these tags an option for you?

Comment: Yes.It is <br> tag

Comment: @AsonCheeSoon I updated my answer, but now you have two strings, is that usable?

Comment: @AsonCheeSoon That means that there's no `<br>` present in the string. There might be a short product description with a `<br>` and without. And perhaps there are descriptions with multiple `<br>` in them. One last try: Use `$product_short_description = str_replace("<br>", "\n", $product_short_description);` that will change `<br>` to a real newline, perhaps your webshop API likes that better?

Comment: Oh I see. If I put *list($modelNo, $inTheBox) = explode("\n", $product_short_description);* , the result also same *Notice: Undefined offset: 1*

Comment: @AsonCheeSoon I'll put the code in my answer, that comment has become unreadable.

Comment: Never mind. I will try to understand. Thanks you take the time to teach me.

Comment: Yes. Your code can run. But the online shopping show me the product_short_description still combined together.

Comment: @AsonCheeSoon And now you know why: The webshop API won't accept HTML tags, and it doesn't work with real newlines. The only other option is to split the string first and feed the webshop API several strings. That might also not be possible. Weird webshop API!

Comment: Can you show me other option is to split the string first and feed the webshop API several strings

Comment: I'll roll back my answer.

Comment: @AsonCheeSoon That will split the string. `explode()` returns an array, and you don't have to use `list()`.

Comment: Ok. Thanks.@KIKO software

Comment: Good morning @KIKO software. Can you solve this problem? Thanks.